# How can I measure the execution time of a npm/yarn task/script?

Tags: time, npm, task, measure, yarnpkg

How can I measure the execution time of a npm/yarn task on the command line without modifying the scripts.

In my special use case I want to execute an existing E2E-Test (yarn test:e2e) 100 times and take the average value.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could use the npm package [gnomon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gnomon):

A command line utility, a bit like moreutils's ts, to prepend timestamp information to the standard output of another command.

Install it like this:

```
$ npm i -g gnomon
```

With this you could run:

```
$ yarn install | gnomon
```

And it might give you an output like this:

```
$ yarn install | gnomon 
   0.5327s   yarn install v1.9.4
   1.9652s   [1/4] Resolving packages...
   0.0160s   success Already up-to-date.
   0.0163s   Done in 2.38s.
   0.0003s   

     Total   2.5315s
```

Comment: What does `|` means?

Comment: `|` is Unix' pipe operator, details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)

Comment: This does not work for me (on windows). It prints the time for some of the tasks (which are really fast) and claims the total time is less than a second. But then there are other tasks that take much longer which are not shown at all. (The overall script takes almost 2 minutes)

Comment: sorry, I use linux/unix/mac only, no idea about windows

Comment: Note: even though this is up-voted, it doesn't seem to work anymore, or work with `pnpm`. The repo has been archived.

Comment: It's not working, it's showing 0.006s in my project where I have 100s of packages

Answer (score 43):

Use the following command in unix

```
time npm run build
```

For windows use this command

```
Measure-Command { start-process npm 'run build' -wait}
```

Comment: Note: powershell-specific, which means that anyone who uses `cmd` for maximum cross-platform compatibility still doesn't have a solution (`cmd` supports `&&`, for example. Kind of essential in the world of node scripts)

Comment: Nice trick! :) I guess it only works in PowerShell. Of course you only get the total timing (and you don't see the script output as it's run in a separate shell). But still good for basic tests!

Comment: If you want to see output include a pipe to write-host and also you can run the command in current scope.
```
Measure-Command { npm 'run build'  | write-host }
```

Comment: thanks! It gives three time values: real/user/sys. Any input about what those measure?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want any global or even local dependencies for this, or you don't want something that only works on unixy operating systems, this is almost trivially achieved with a simple .js file and an equally simple npm script refinement:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts: {
    "time": "node mark.js",
    "start": "npm run time && ...whatever 'start' was before... && npm run time",
  },
  ...
}
```

With that `mark.js` file being the almost trivial following code:

```
const fs = require("fs"); // or import fs from "fs"; if you're working on modern JS

const timingFile = `.timing`;

if(fs.existsSync(timingFile)) {
  const end = Date.now();
  const start = fs.readFileSync(timingFile);
  fs.unlinkSync(timingFile);
  console.log(`Runtime: ${(end - start)/1000}s`);
} else { fs.writeFileSync(timingFile, `${Date.now()}`, `utf8`); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @user1816491 answer, I remembered that I used to use a shell utility, `ts`.

In unix (`apt` is for debian/ubuntu), install `moreutils` that contains `ts`, as e.g.

```
sudo apt install moreutils -y
```

Then e.g.

```
$ npm run build | ts '%FT%T'
2022-08-24T09:55:13 
2022-08-24T09:55:13 > build
2022-08-24T09:55:13 > next build
2022-08-24T09:55:13
```

or

```
$ npm run build | ts -s '[%H:%M:%.S]'
[00:00:00.416378] 
[00:00:00.416511] > build
[00:00:00.416577] > next build
[00:00:00.416603]
```